# How to show selection items in ionic ion-select similar to datepicker?

Tags: select, ionic-framework, datepicker

How can I show my  items like the datepicker? At the moment, I just see a popup where I can choose from. I want it to be scrollable

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2gL8.png]

Comment: You can use ion-select component of ionic to achieve this check this link : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/

Comment: I check all of them, but they are mostly popups. None of them look like the datepicker which I attached :(

Answer (score 0):

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/date-picker/

with this native plugin you can use the native date picker of the underlying OS.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to use the date-picker. I am just interested in the illustration. I want to show a list of items but in a view like datepicker, just the names of the items instead of the dates. Sorry for the misunderstandings